# Installing OAuth PECL package on PHP 5 on OS X

Tags: php, macos, oauth, pecl, php-5.5

I'm trying to install the OAuth PECL package, and I'm using PHP 5.
When I run the install command, I get the error below that I must have PHP version 7.0.
Upgrading to PHP 7 is not an option right now, so how do I get the OAuth package installed for PHP 5?

```
chris$ sudo pecl install oauth
pecl/oauth requires PHP (version >= 7.0.0), installed version is 5.5.29
No valid packages found
install failed
```

Comment: See my edit also, yeah, you're stuck with `1.2.3` :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems like the dependencies are messed up for Version 2.0.0 of `oauth`. You can install the previous version like this:

```
sudo pecl install oauth-1.2.3
```

I also filed an issue on their GitHub project on your behalf ([here](https://github.com/Sean-Der/pecl-web_services-oauth/issues/2)), as this seems to be an unintentional bug.

In [`package.xml`](https://github.com/Sean-Der/pecl-web_services-oauth/blob/04ef1302564576d7a18e363d9717c6f80037091c/package.xml), we have:

```
<required>
  <php>
    <min>7.0.0</min>
  </php>

  <!-- ... -->
</required>
```

**Edit**

Looks like there's some news from the bug report. Indeed, version 2.0.0 only supports PHP7 and the changelog was unclear. The maintainer of `oauth` has filed [a bug against PECL](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71224) to install the latest compatible version. So, yes, you're stuck with 1.2.3 and the instructions above are correct.

**Edit Again**

It looks like PECL won't be fixing this any time soon, so we're stuck installing the specific version :)

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Thanks for investigating that!

Comment: No problem! Hey @Hemc, what error are you getting trying to install 1.2.3? Make sure you're installing it with `sudo` also.

Answer (score 1):

Extending upon the already accepted answer
If you are facing compilation errors like I did most probably you are using some application like MAMP.
Unfortunately the latest version of MAMP doesn't include all the components of php.
To install the missing headers download the respective php source code.
Source code for `php-5.6.10` can be downloaded from [here](https://www.php.net/get/php-5.6.10.tar.gz/from/a/mirror)

After downloading the source code extract it in the `php` folder under `include/php` in my case the php folder was located at `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10` so I extracted files under `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/include/php`.

**Note:**
When you extract the files they are extracted in a folder like `php-version` in my case it was `php-5.6.10` rename it to `php` and then move it to `include` folder.

Now go to `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/include/php` and then run `./configure` this should build the required header files and then you can install `oauth`.